# Optimizing complex functions

Tags: complex, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimize a function containing complex numbers, however I keep running into errors. Consider the simple optimization problem:

```
z = x + I*y;
f = Abs[z - (1 + I)^2];
FindMinimum[f, {x, y}]
```

The output is:

```
Out[1]={1.2824*10^-8, {x -> -3.00754*10^-9, y -> 2.}}
```

which seems to be correct.
The functions I will try to optimize is more complicated, so I am trying to use the next formulation:

```
z[x_, y_] := x + I*y;
f[x_, y_] := Abs[z[x, y] - (1 + I)^2];
FindMinimum[f, {x, y}]
```

In this case I get the error message:

```
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value f is not a real number at {x,y} = {1.,1.}. >>
```

Is there a way to optimize complex functions using `function`s in Mathematica? Or any advice that could help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the variables in the FindMinimum command:

```
z[x_, y_] := x + I*y;
f[x_, y_] := Abs[z[x, y] - (1 + I)^2];
FindMinimum[f[x,y], {x, y}]

Out[1]={1.28247*10^-8, {x -> -3.00876*10^-9, y -> 2.}}
```